# how to grep for a pattern in a few set of files under a directory?

Tags: awk, grep

i have a large number of files under a directory. out of that i need to search for a pattern ONLY in files which were created/last modified on the month of November. By using Awk and xargs command i was able to acheive this. But I would like to know whether there is a simple grep command to acheive the same. Below is the command which I used

```
ls -ltr |grep "Nov"|awk '{print $9}'|xargs grep -i (pattern)
```

Could you please help me on this one ?

Comment: `grep` is a tool for searching for a pattern in a file and printing the matching line (`g/re/p` get it?). `find` is a tool for finding files (`FIND`ing get it?). So, you would not use `grep` to `FIND` files just like you would not use `find` to `g/re/p` within files. Hopefully that narrows down your choices on which tool to use for which parts of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the find command:

```
find . -newermt 2013-11-1 ! -newermt 2013-11-30 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i pattern
```